# OpenSSL generate certificate chain

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I found this service https://whatsmychaincert.com/ that generate a chain (with the root) by pasting a certificate.

There is any way for generate the chain with OpenSSL?

I have found this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts
```

that show all certificate chain, but requires that the certificate is already online.

there is any way for generate the chain with a local file certificate?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s_client -showcerts` shows the chain *as provided by the server*; this *should* be the full chain optionally less root, but as that website says some servers aren't configured correctly. It also has a link "How does this work" which as one might expect explains how it works:

> mkcertchain is a utility for building a chain of intermediate certificates
>   for an SSL certificate.  It downloads the chain certificate from the URL
>   specified in the certificate's "CA Issuers" field, recurring until
>   encountering a root certificate that's trusted in all major browsers.
>   If multiple certificate chains are found, the shortest one is used.

Given a starting cert in a file, or outputtable by some program (such as perhaps a database query), in either PEM or 'DER' (binary) format, `openssl x509 -text [-inform pem|der]` outputs all of the cert data including 'CA Issuers'. Any number of text-handling programs like awk, perl, grep, shells such as bash, or PowerShell, should be able to extract that line and its value, and since it is normally http:, any number of HTTP-request programs like curl and wget can fetch the cert. Any scripting language like perl, shell or PowerShell can iterate this process as needed, stopping when a root is hit by comparing Subject and Issuer. If you want to stop at an anchor that is not a root that's a little more complicated, but I don't think any such anchors are currently accepted by major browsers, thus aren't needed for the purpose of building a chain to be accepted by browsers.

FWIW, even if your certs *don't* have the CA Issuers field in AIA, most public CAs including intermediates have now been captured by the certificate transparency logs, which are easily searchable at https://crt.sh ; you can easily navigate through the chain just by clicking links so I haven't thought about trying to automate it, although presumably the numerous tools that 'drive' or simulate a web browser to interact with a website would work here.

And of course, the CA that issued your cert in the first place should *always* be able to supply the needed chain certs; it's part of their job.